# Set Y labels from a text file - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib, I have plotted the following graph from a text file. I have a series of values that are stored in another text file that I want to use the represent the Y axis on this graph.

[image]

The values will therefore be this:

[image]

Essentially, instead of displaying `0, 24, 40, ....., 16` it will show the frequencies represented in the text file, between `0, 1000, ....., 6000`

Any help would be greatly thankful!

Comment: I guess there is a relationship between the values you're currently displaying and the frequencies in the text file? Perhaps write a function to map your values into frequencies?